# Как узнать сколько прошло времени с 01.04.2019 на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите код или статью, нужно узнать сколько времени прошло от даты 01.04.2019 до сегодня. Время должно отображать только год и месяц(1 year 2 month)

Comment: можно воспользоваться библиотекой moment.js в ней можно посчитать разницу между датами

Comment: @slippyk, для разницы в месяцах и годах это решение не подходит :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот так примерно:

```js
// находим в теле HTML контейнер, куда будем выводить результат
var res = document.getElementById("place");

// объявляем наши даты
var current = new Date(); // сегодня
var old = new Date("2019-04-01"); // !!! год-месяц-день !!!

// сначала находим количество дней между датами
var days = Math.ceil(Math.abs(old.getTime() - current.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
var year = Math.floor(days / 365); // вычисляем кол-во лет. Math.floor убирает остаток.
var months = Math.floor((days - (year * 365)) / 30); // отняв года, вычисляем месяцы

// осталось вывести полученную информацию в контейнер:
res.innerHTML = 'С даты 01.04.2019 прошло: ' + year + ' год, ' + months + ' месяцев';
```

```html
<div id="place"></div>
```

Желаю удачи в обучении!

Comment: но ведь сейчас 02.07.2020 с 1.04.2019 прошло не 1год 6 месяцев, а 1 год и 3 месяца

Comment: почему, кстати, в году 360 дней стало? :)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, исправил (торопился), забыл что дата пишется по извращенски (ММ-ДД-ГГГГ)

Comment: @Rikky, хм, интересно - [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/ODzThO8.png)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 где выполняете код? Даже если тут нажать на сниппет (выполнить код) - [скрин](https://yadi.sk/i/cz6xJXzcjeFvBQ)

Comment: @Rikky, да, тут в сниппете (Мозила)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 очень странно, мб js выключен? О_о у меня всё работает, всё показывает

Comment: @Rikky, нет. Почему-то не сразу дошло, ошибка в написание даты, как бы стандарт [`YYYY-MM-DD`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Интересно почему в вашем браузере работает..

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 так тоже работает. Ну допустим, изменил - теперь работает?)))

Comment: Внесу свои 5 копеек, в году не всегда 365 дней ;-).

Comment: @Rikky, ну в документации такой стандарт, значит нужно использовать правильный вариант. Теперь работает.

Comment: @Node_pro, всегда, только это не совсем верно, точнее будет 365 дней и 6 часов)